# duplicity not pushing backups to OVH swift container

Tags: backup, object-storage, ovh, duplicity

I have an issue with duplicity 0.7.06 and 0.7.19 backup tool when trying to auth using keystone V3 with OVH.
Duplicity creates only local backups in `.cache/duplicity` but does not push them to OVH swift object storage. There are no errors it just keeps storing them on local disk.
It was working before with keystone auth V2, credentials are the same. I was able to login to swift using those credentials but duplicity does not work...

Here's the command I am using with environmental settings:

```
export SWIFT_AUTHURL="https://auth.cloud.ovh.net/v3/"
export SWIFT_USERNAME="xxxx"
export SWIFT_PASSWORD="xxxxx"
export SWIFT_REGION_NAME="SBG"
export SWIFT_USER_DOMAIN_NAME="Default"
export SWIFT_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME="default"
export SWIFT_TENANTNAME="xxxx"
export SWIFT_AUTHVERSION="3"
export PASSPHRASE="xxxx"

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
duplicity /home swift://${HOSTNAME}
```

Anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

try duplicity 0.8. version 0.7 outdated ..ede/duoly.net

Comment: (From the review queue, don't @ me!) Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Unless you know for a fact that upgrading to version 0.8 will solve the problem, this sort of answer should be left as a comment. I know new users aren't allowed to leave comments, this is just advice for the future.